# how to display radio button input with if else statement as output in a text box

Tags: javascript, html

I need help again for my HTML project. I have radio buttons on the page and I want to display the output on a text box depending on the radio button selected. For example, if I choose yes then the output should be "process item for pickup service" and if I choose no the output should ne "pickup service N/A". At the moment the code that I have displays both values for Yes and No. What if else codes do I need to fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
    function showInput(){
    var ui1 = document.getElementById('pickup').value;
    var ui2 = document.getElementById('xpickup').value;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = ui1 + '\n' + ui2 + '\n';
    }
    </script>  

    <form action="">
    <p> For Pick-up Service? </p>
    <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="pickup" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="xpickup" name="pickup" value="No"> No<br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="showInput();">Generate</button><br/>
    <p><textarea name="generated notes" cols="75" rows="20" id='display' >
    </textarea></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're submitting the form so the page is going to refresh. You either need to use Ajax to submit the form or have the message returned using PHP or whatever server side language you're processing the form through.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var pickupradios = document.getElementsByName('pickup');
var pickupval;
for(var i = 0; i < pickupradios.length; i++){
    if(pickupradios[i].checked) pickupval = pickupradios[i].value;
}
//then time to use pickupval
```

Answer (score 0):

`function showInput(){
    var result = document.querySelector("input[name='pickup']").value;
     if(result =='Yes'){
      document.getElementById('display').value="process item for pickup                                                                               service";
     }
     else if(result =='No'){
             document.getElementById('display').value="pickup service N/A";
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Do with some [`data`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2i_GjsOzUAhUGZlAKHXOPBxEQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FHTMLElement%2Fdataset&usg=AFQjCNFss8rHH_L6fDL-au6OnkQHadtaUg) attribute .And `querySelectorAll()` used for find the checked value

```js
function showInput() {
var res = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')[0].dataset.print
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <p> For Pick-up Service? </p>
  <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="pickup" value="Yes" data-print="process item for pickup service"> Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" id="xpickup" name="pickup" value="No" data-print="pickup service N/a"> No<br>
</form>
<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="showInput();">Generate</button><br/>
<p><textarea name="generated notes" cols="75" rows="20" id='display'>
    </textarea></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code , check radio button values and set innerHTML

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
    function showInput(){
   var value= document.querySelector('input[name="pickup"]:checked').value;
   if(value=="Yes")
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML="process item for pickup service"
    else
 document.getElementById('display').innerHTML="pickup service N/A"
    
    }
    </script>  

    <form action="">
    <p> For Pick-up Service? </p>
    <input type="radio"  name="pickup" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="pickup" value="No"> No<br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="showInput();">Generate</button><br/>
    <p><textarea name="generated notes" cols="75" rows="20" id='display' >
    </textarea></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: how about if I want to put a longer content if "Yes" is selected? like for example below:

- submit service booking form 
- informed the customer about the email which contains: 
a) The connote that needs to be printed for courier collection
b) Instructions for how to correctly package the device
- advised of disclaimers: NFF, CID, Liquid Damage, Loss of Data, Customized OS/Rooted Device, International Warranty
- provided Support Ticket Number - 

I tried to replace the value you put in the Yes option but the script just stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for:

```
function showInput(){
    var outputText;
    if(document.getElementById('pickup').checked) {
        outputText = "Process item for pickup service";
    }else if(document.getElementById('xpickup').checked) {
        outputText = "Pickup service N/A";
    }
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = outputText;
}
```